# is there a word or phrase meaning "to falsely believe one's opinion/feedback is being considered"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Here is an example: In a conversation, one is asked their opinion regarding a decision, but the decision has already been made—so the individual being asked is led to believe (falsely) that their opinion might have an impact on the outcome.

> "Jane **[falsely believed her opinion was considered]** when her boss asked her who she thought was the best candidate for a job; however, she was not aware that her boss had already selected a candidate to hire."

Or perhaps there is a word meaning "to believe one's opinion is being considered" and the proper use would be to add "falsely" before that word.

Comment: The closest idiom I can think of is to say that Jane’s boss was only paying *lip service* to Jane’s opinion on the candidates. Not sure if that helps.